# Generating covariance matrix from ENVI binary file of SAR polarimetric image?

Tags: synthetic-aperture-radar

I have ENVI binary files of SAR polarimetric image.

How can the covariance matrix [c2] be generated from the image?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the complex data, you can use simple band math equations in ENVI to generate elements of the C2 Matrix.